# Posfix settings without a domain/host name

Tags: centos, vps, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have a VPS server that only deals with email hosting. This server does not have any designated domain name pointing to it. Its only one VPS with one IP address.

I am running CentOS 6.5 Minimal, 32bit with Postfix and Dovecot installed. This is currently what my `etc/postfix/main.cf` looks like (for domain/hosting attributes).

```
# INTERNET HOST AND DOMAIN NAMES
#
# The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
# mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
# from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
# other configuration parameters.
#
myhostname =   
#myhostname =

# The mydomain parameter specifies the local internet domain name.
# The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component.
# $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration
# parameters.
#
mydomain =     
# SENDING MAIL
#
# The myorigin parameter specifies the domain that locally-posted
# mail appears to come from. The default is to append $myhostname,
# which is fine for small sites.  If you run a domain with multiple
# machines, you should (1) change this to $mydomain and (2) set up
# a domain-wide alias database that aliases each user to
# user@that.users.mailhost.
#
# For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses,
# myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended
# to recipient addresses that have no @domain part.
#
#myorigin = $myhostname
myorigin = $mydomain
```

As you might have noticed, both `myhostname` & `mydomain` fields are empty. The reason for this is, the server doesn't really have a domain or hostname. What should I be doing in this case?

I have an `M` record pointing to `mail.my-domain.tld` and `MX` record pointing to `mail.my-domain.tld`

Can I use `mail.my-domain.tld` for both as `mydomain =` and `myhostname =` in `main.cf`? Because `my-domain.tld` is pointing to another VPS with another IP, which takes care of only web hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `myhostname` - The internet hostname of this mail system. Here use `mail.my-domain.tld`
- `mydomain` - The internet domain name of this mail system. The default is to use
  `$myhostname` minus the first component.`$mydomain` is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters. So here use `my-domain.tld`

This VPS (mail server) can just serve your mail traffic and as you said your `my-domain.tld` web hosting can be in a different VPS server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand how I can use `$mydomain = my-domain.tld` when clearly infact, `my-domain.tld` is not associated with this server. It is poiting to another host, with different IP.

Comment: You can, because this server is handling mail for `my-domain.tld`. May be you can have a different server for handling web traffic for `my-domain.tld`